# Capillary action of water in a sealed vessel

Tags: fluid-dynamics, elasticity, capillary-action

Consider a vessel completely filled with water and a vertically oriented capillary. If the water vessel was open at the top, you would expect capillary action to occur, lowering the water level in the vessel until a force equilibrium is reached. However, if we seal the vessel, the water would have to increase its volume/reduce its density for capillary action to take place, as no air can enter the vessel to fill up the volume. Does the (high) bulk modulus of water also apply here, as this expansion is nothing else than negative compression, i. e. would the hydrogen bridge bonds mostly suppress capillary action?